# Реализация уведомлений в режиме реального времени по WebSocket

Tags: node.js, websocket

В данный момент уведомления в принципе работают, однако подход который я использую мне мягко говоря не нравится.
У меня на сайте часть бэкенда на PHP часть на NODEJS. На ноде в основном это чат и все уведомления. Для уведомлений используется WebSocket. 
Если один из пользователей добавляет другого в друзья, то вместе с запросом уходит ID пользователя котого мы добавляем.
У каждого пользователя в DOM есть ID, т.е. когда один из пользователей посылает запрос, этот запрос приходит на клиент и сравнивает какой ИД есть у текущего пользователя.
Если ИД совпадает уведомление показываем.
    Хотелось бы переделать данную реализацию, но как более граммотно подойти к текущему вопросу пока не нашёл.
    Каким образом лучше реализовать данное решение? Любые ссылки где можно почитать о подобных реализациях будут так же весьма полезны.

Comment: у вас все клиенты получают все уведомления?

Comment: Вообще вроде бы все. Во всяком случае багов я пока с уведомлениями не находил.

Comment: я имел ввиду, что ни получают и свои и чужие?

Comment: Нет, получают только свои. Но по сути, когда отправляется уведомление, JS выполняется у всех клиентов, но уведомление показывает только тому, у которого соответствуют данные

Comment: для начала начните пересылать клиенту только его сообщения, то есть фильтруйте их на сервере.

Comment: Отфильтровать на сервере это без проблем, но я не очень понимаю как сделать уведомление только одному пользователю. Есть ли какой - то пример, как на клиенте получать сообщение только для нужного пользователя?